# Data in the UITableView get duplicated when back button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I working on a project that is written in swift 3.0. My requirement is to save data (on CoreData) that I enter on some text fields and populate one of those attributes in to a table view, thus once a row is selected I wants to update that record (re-assign values on my text fields and save).

Basically I have an entity named "Task" and it got three attributes, and I wants to populate one of those attributes(called "name") that I have saved on core data, in to a table view. Hence when I wants to edit the data that I entered, I tap on a row and it'll direct me to the ViewController where I initially entered those data. However when I click the back button without saving the data it'll duplicate the array and populate in my table view. how can I stop this. The code of the table view class as follow.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableViewController:  UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var stores = [Store] ()

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.tableView.reloadData()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "Store")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false



    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [Store]



        // check data existance
        if results.count>0 {
            print(results.count)

            for resultGot in results {

                if let expName = resultGot.name {
                    print("expence name is :", expName)

                    stores += [resultGot]

                    print("my array is : \(stores)")
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }catch{


        print("No Data to load")
    }


  }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stores.count
  }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell ()


    let store = stores [indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = store.name

    //cell.textLabel?.text = myExpensesArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
   }



  @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

  }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "editStore", sender: nil)

 }
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editStore"{

        let v = segue.destination as! ViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let row = indexPath?.row
        v.store = stores[row!]


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because already loaded elements are present inside your array. When you came back to previously loaded `ViewController` its method `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` called everytime according to the `viewController's` life cycle.

You need to clear your previously loaded array using `removeAll()` method when you came back.

Use below code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    stores.removeAll()  // clears all element   

    let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "Store")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [Store]
        // check data existance
        if results.count>0 {
            print(results.count)

            for resultGot in results {
                if let expName = resultGot.name {
                    print("expence name is :", expName)
                    stores += [resultGot]
                    print("my array is : \(stores)")
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }catch{
        print("No Data to load")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You populate your tableView in the `viewDidAppear` method which is execute everytime the view is shown (either for first time or coming back from a anbother detail view controller).

You either

- populate it once by moving the populate code to viewDidLoad
- or clean (remove all objects from) the stores before repopulating it, if you need fresh data to be shown. so before `for resultGot in results`

insert something like

```
stores = []
```

Comment: Sir if I clear all the code from viewWillAppear and load them in to viewDidLoad where am i supposed to reload my tableView?? because when i add a new entry or edit it, it wont display the new entry or the updated one in my tableView

Comment: Then just reset the stores variable before refilling it with fresh data, as said in second point